# How to know when you return from a Fragment to an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I add a fragment from an `Activity`, and then close that fragment, how am I able to track this? The issues I am running into with this scenario are the following:

> Adding a fragment does not call any Activity life cycles, so I have no onPause/onResume to bail me out
>
> I am not starting a new Activity, so starting the Activity for results isn't viable.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.example.keralapolice;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;


public class ChiefFragment extends Fragment {
View view;

// public OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chief, container, false);
    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i(getTag(), "keyCode: " + keyCode);
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().show();
                Log.i(getTag(), "onKey Back listener is working!!!");
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                // String cameback="CameBack";
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), home.class);
                // i.putExtra("Comingback", cameback);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the support version, in the `AppCompatActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
}
```

Comment: onResumeFragments does not get called when you return back to the Activity from a fragment.

Comment: Another way is to use `getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener();`

Comment: Neil is right. Another way is also to use listeners as stated in the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
under the header 'Creating event callbacks to the activity'

Comment: That is what I needed! Thank you Neil

Answer (score 0):

As Neil mentioned, this can be done using `getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener();`

The implementation I did was the following:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                // do some logic

            }
        });
```